# jQuery. Add and remove elements working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It seemed like nothing special but...
I'm trying to add and remove div, add element function working as expected, but if I delete element, nothing else are working - I cannot add nor delete. And one more problem there - selectors using css class that are same for all elements, but event triggering only on first element.
Here is JS:

```
//Here i want to clone element and insert its after last element    
$("div.addnewitem").on('click', function () {
                    var $d = $("div.item:first").clone();
                    $($d).insertAfter("div.item:last");
                });
//Here i'm deleting element
                $("div.deleteitem").on('click', function (event) {
                    $(event.target).closest("div.item").remove();
                });
```

And HTML markup:

```
    <div class="item">
            <div class="itemphoto">
                <img alt="" src="../img/woolrich.png">
            </div>
            <div class="bigshadow">
                <img alt="" src="../img/bigshadow.png">
            </div>
<!--This must add new element after last one-->
            <div class="addnewitem">
                <img alt="" src="../img/addnewitem.png">
            </div>
<!--This must delete current div-->
            <div class="deleteitem">
                <img alt="" src="../img/deleteitem.png">
            </div>
            <div class="about">
                <input type="text" class="link" placeholder="Ссылка на вещь..." name="item_url">
                <input type="text" class="link" placeholder="Ссылка на изображение" name="item_image" />
                <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Вещь и бренд..." name="item_name">
                <textarea class="review" placeholder="Короткое описание (около 120 символов)..." name="item_desc"></textarea>
                <input type="text" class="pricestylist" placeholder="Цена (xxx руб/$)" name="item_price">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Looks like $(event.target).closest("div.item").remove() traverses up the dom and removes your main <div class="item">

Comment: Mmm, not sure. Actually div.item is the element that I add and remove but not the first element. I'm manipulating with added elements.

Comment: Do you really want to always clone the first item or the one that they copy is actually clicked for? Your current selector always clones the first

Comment: Yes, right, the first only, as this is element that never change. But i want to manipulate (delete actually) with cloned elements. That's why on add action I'm using div.item:first, but on delete action event.target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g5p69do/) demo

`first").clone(true);` , the true was missing, it is withDataAndEvents attribute,

for more details, check [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)